# Manipulate iFrame content in Adobe AIr

Tags: iframe, air, adobe

Is it possible in Adobe Air to manipulate a website loaded into an iFrame?  Like say I want to automate filling out a repetitive form that I need to fill out on a regular basis with data that I have stored into a database.  I want it to fill out the fields that I know the selectors of and make it click the submit button.  Possible?  If not.. what about Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I believe this ought to be possible. When you load a web page into an AIR app with [HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html), it gets populated with a `window` property that points to the root of the Javascript DOM inside that web page, which you should be able to manipulate.

See [the code snippet here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f09.html), for example, which only manipulates CSS, but form elements ought to work the same way as far as I know.